# 3D surface plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to create a 3D plot in R-Project. I know there was a question like this before but I couldn't solve my problems with the answers there.

What I have is:

```
Vdot_L = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Qdot_verd = c(2000,2100,2200,2300,2400,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900,3000) 
zeta_ex = 0.4
T_U = 293.15 #K
T_verd = 273.15 #K
T_cond=Vdot_L*2+T_U
epsilon_k = zeta_ex * T_verd/(T_cond - T_verd)
Pfun <- function(a,b) {a/b}
P    <- outer(Qdot_verd, epsilon_k, FUN="Pfun")
```

What I'd like to create is a colored surface plot with `Vdot_L` on the x-Axis, `Qdot_verd` on the y-Axis and `P` on the z-Axis. I'm thanful for every help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So something like this??

[image]

```
library(rgl)
zlim        <- range(P,na.rm=T)
zlen        <- zlim[2] - zlim[1] + 1
color.range <- rev(rainbow(zlen))       # height color lookup table
colors      <- color.range[P-zlim[1]+1] # assign colors to heights for each point
persp3d(Vdot_L, Qdot_verd, P, col=colors)
```

Comment: thats perfect, thx! Now I have the problem that I can't adjust the limits of my z axis. what I tried is 'persp3d(Vdot_L, Qdot_verd, P, col=colors, zlim=c(0,500))' but nothing happens... no error message and no reaction in the plot... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you investigated the Plot3D package?
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/plot3D.pdf
There's a method in here called `surf3d` which seems like it would do what you want. After importing the package, cast your values to matrix and write:

```
surf3d(Vdot_L, Qdot_verd, P)
```

There's also a color parameter which you can adjust.

Alternatively, use rgl, and avoid the matrix issue:

```
rgl.surface(Vdot_L, Qdot_verd, P)
```

Also check out these posts for more info:
[R: 3D surface plot from 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225752/r-3d-surface-plot-from-2d-matrix?rq=1)
[How to create 3D - MATLAB style - surface plots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549540/how-to-create-3d-matlab-style-surface-plots-in-r)

Comment: thx for your answer!
I already tried this. It gives me the error "'x' should be a matrix". And I don't understand why.

Comment: So x has to be a matrix in this case, so I think you need to cast it using `matrix(Vdot_L, nrow = ?, ncol = ?)` And specify the number of rows/columns.

Comment: Here's a question: are you trying to make this like a scatterplot, where each point has x,y,z coordinates of the corresponding values in each data list?

Comment: Actually, why don't you use `rgl.surface()` instead? I think that's more in line with what you want.

Comment: the rgl.surface sounds exactly like what i'm looking for. But the result what I get in the moment is just a flat surface. it should look more bended. I have to catch up the train. i'll try it more later... thanks!

Comment: It is NOT a flat surface, but rather one with a very small curvature. You need to look at your inputs and understand that the x inputs are going up at roughly the same rate as your y inputs are going down, so not a very dramatic "bend" will be produced.