# How to plot a surface in rgl plot3d

Tags: r, rgl

So I have this code that produces the exact surface

```
f = function(x, y){
    z = ((x^2)+(3*y^2))*exp(-(x^2)-(y^2))
}
plot3d(f, col = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white")), 
       xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z", 
       xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3),
       aspect = c(1, 1, 0.5))
```

Giving the following plot:
[image: 3d exact plot]
Now I have some code that does a random walk metropolis algorithm to reproduce the above image. I think it works as if I do another plot of these calculated values I get the next image with 500 points. Here is the code

```
open3d()
plot3d(x0, y0, f(x0, y0), type = "p")
```

Which gives the following plot:
[image]
I know it's hard looking at this still image but being able to rotate the sampling is working.

Now here is my question: How can I use `plot3d()` so that I can have a surface that connects all these points and gives a more jagged representation of the exact plot? Or how can I have each point in the z axis as a bar from the xy plane? I just want something more 3 dimensional than points and I can't find how to do this.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by triangulating the surface.  You don't give us your actual data, but I can create some similar data using

```
f = function(x, y){
    z = ((x^2)+(3*y^2))*exp(-(x^2)-(y^2))
}
x <- runif(500, -3, 3)
y <- runif(500, -3, 3)
z <- f(x, y)
```

Then the plotting is done using the method in `?persp3d.deldir`:

```
library(deldir)
library(rgl)
col <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white"))(20)[1 + round(19*(z - min(z))/diff(range(z)))]
dxyz <- deldir::deldir(x, y, z = z, suppressMsge = TRUE)
persp3d(dxyz, col = col, front = "lines", back = "lines")
```

This might need some cosmetic fixes, e.g.

```
aspect3d(2, 2, 1)
```

After some rotation, this gives me the following plot:

[image]

Comment: I think this gives the closest thing to what I was looking for and there is no extra points being added to the data as with the other answers so this is very nice thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand what you want. If my understanding is correct, here is a solution. Define a parametric representation of your surface:

```
fx <- function(u,v) u
fy <- function(u,v) v
fz <- function(u,v){
  ((u^2)+(3*v^2))*exp(-(u^2)-(v^2))
}
```

Let's say you have these points:

```
x0 <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 20)
y0 <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 20)
```

Then you can use the function `parametric3d` of the `misc3d` package, with the option `fill=FALSE` to get a wireframe:

```
library(misc3d)
parametric3d(fx, fy, fz, u=x0, v=y0, 
             color="blue", fill = FALSE)
```

[image]

Is it what you want?

To get some vertical bars, use the function `segments3d` of `rgl`:

```
i <- 8
bar <- rbind(c(x0[i],y0[i],0),c(x0[i],y0[i],f(x0[i],y0[i])))
segments3d(bar, color="red")
```

Comment: Hmm... Finally I think that `parametric3d` is not appropriate, because it creates a grid of points from `x0` and `y0`. But maybe it's possible to modify the source code to get something appropriate.

Comment: Wow no I think this is good, thanks! I will try something similar and see how it looks but I’ll try and say again. What I wanted was for all the points to be connected by a net and this looks promising. I’m also new to the package and the language so I wasn’t sure of what function in the package might do what I was looking for but I think your greater knowledge has helped me.

Comment: @MRT I'm not sure... With `parametric3d` you give `x0` and `y0` and the points are those of the grid `expand.grid(x0, y0)`. There's no need that `x0` and `y0` have the same length. While in your case you don't want a grid.

Comment: True I don't want a grid but I have just tried running it with my 1000 point resolution and it all merges together to give a smooth blue surface. One question I would like to ask is do you know enough about this function `parametric3d` to tell me how I can have the box around like the scatter plot I have in the question?

Comment: Oh wait there is a problem. When I use only a few points the surface should look much more jagged then it does but I can't show images so I'll post a new answer after this

Comment: @MRT The parametric plot with `parametric3D` is rendered in `rgl`. So you can use any `rgl` function. For the bounding box, the `rgl` function `bbox3d` does it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plot with only 50 points using my original code.

[image: Scatter graph of 50 points]

When I then apply what was said by Stéphane Laurent I then get this plot which feels too accurate when given the actual points I have

[image: wire plot]

Perhaps you need to explain to me what is actually happening in the function `parametric3d`

Comment: I already explained :-) When, for example, you give `x0 = c(1,2)` and `y0=c(3,4)`, then `parametric3d` uses the points `c(1,3)`, `c(1,4)`, c(2,3)`, c(2,4)` (the grid obtained by "crossing" `x0` and `y0`, the Cartesian product in other words).