# Plot specified area of a surface mesh with color

Tags: r, 3d, interpolation, rgl

I have data for 3D facia surface mesh. Data are available [here](https://github.com/Patricklv/Smoothing-3D-surface/tree/master), where vb.xlsx contains coordinates for 7160 3D vertices and it.xlsx contains face information. The color coding.txt is a matrix of 7160*1 with elements of either 1 or 2. I want the surface area (not just vertices!) enclosed by vertices which are coded 1 to be plotted in a different color from areas covered by vertices coded 2.

For example, if vertices covering nose and upper lip are coded 1 and other facial areas are coded 2, then I wish to make a plot as below:

[image]

where surface area of nose and upper lip is green and other regions are gray.

My code to generate gray color 3D facial surface mesh is as follows:

```
library(geomorph)
library(xlsx)
library(rgl)

# Import data
vb <- read.xlsx("E:\\...\\vb.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = F)
it <- read.xlsx("E:\\...\\it.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = F)

vb_mat <- t(as.matrix(vb))
vb_mat <- rbind(vb_mat, 1)
rownames(vb_mat) <- c("xpts", "ypts", "zpts", "")

it_mat <- t(as.matrix(it))
rownames(it_mat) <- NULL

vertices <- c(vb_mat)
indices <- c(it_mat)

try <- tmesh3d(vertices = vertices, indices = indices, homogeneous = TRUE, material = NULL, 
               normals = NULL, texcoords = NULL)

try2 <- addNormals(try)

shade3d(try2, col="darkgrey", specular = "#202020")
```

Now, I want to plot surface area containing vertices coded 1 with green color and area containing vertices coded 2 with pink color. How should I modify my R code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky thing in colouring surfaces is deciding how to use the colours.  You can colour by vertex, by edge, or by face.  You want to do it by vertex.

As long as you are using `rgl` version 0.100.2 or newer, this is relatively easy.  Specify the colours one per vertex, and use argument `meshColor = "vertices"` to tell `rgl` that's what you did.
For example,

```
shade3d(try2, col=c("green", "pink")[col], meshColor = "vertices", specular = "#202020")
```

which gives

[image: screen capture]

This version of `rgl` isn't on CRAN yet, but it's available on [R-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=234) and [Github](https://github.com/rforge/rgl).

Comment: Thank you! But I also read Stéphane Laurent's code and did not seem to find anything wrong. But why your plot is colored differently from Laurent's, which one should I trust?

Comment: Do an experiment:  set the colour depending on the x, y or z value, and see which one shows it.

Comment: Can you please suggest a line of coding on how to set the colour depending on the x, y or z value, I will do the experiment. Sorry that I am really new to 3D visualization. Due to time limit, I ask several naive questions to you.

Comment: Try `col <- (vb[,3] > quantile(vb[,3], 0.99)) + 1`, which chooses just the 1% largest z values as colour 2, the rest as colour 1.

Comment: @Patrick I've just tried user2554330's idea with my code and I don't get the expected result. Looks like you should trust his/her solution, not mine.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent Thank you. I used rgl version 0.100.10 downloaded from user2554330 recommended R-forge website. Trying your code on this new version of rgl yielded exactly the same results as user2554330's. With the current CRAN version, I got the same plot as yours. So your code is still right, but I do not know why it only works on the new version.

Comment: The default before `meshColor` was added was really weird, and has changed to `"vertices"` in 0.100.x (but you get a warning if you depend on the default).  You get the old behaviour using `meshColor = "legacy"`.

Comment: @user2554330 Another quick question. I get wireframe using `wire3d(try2, col="darkgrey", specular = "#202020")` and continuous surface using `shade3d(try2, col="darkgrey", specular = "#202020")`. Is there a way to show both wireframe and surface mesh simultaneously in one 3D plot?

Comment: Yes, see the first example in `?rgl::persp3d` in the development version of `rgl`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the expected result?

```
library(rgl)
library(readxl)
# Import data
vb <- read_xlsx("vb.xlsx", sheet = 1, col_names = FALSE)
it <- read_xlsx("it.xlsx", sheet = 1, col_names = FALSE)
colorCoding <- read.table("Color coding.txt")$V1
colors <- c("darkgrey","midnightblue")[colorCoding]

vb_mat <- rbind(t(as.matrix(vb)), 1)
rownames(vb_mat) <- c("xpts", "ypts", "zpts", "")
it_mat <- t(as.matrix(it))
rownames(it_mat) <- NULL
vertices <- c(vb_mat)
indices <- c(it_mat)

mesh <- addNormals(
  tmesh3d(vertices = vertices, indices = indices, homogeneous = TRUE,
          material = list(color=colors)))
shade3d(mesh, specular = "#202020")
```

[image]

Comment: Thx. I don't know what is "the expected" plot. The coding numbers are generated from hierarchical spectural clustering as described in "Genome-wide mapping of global-to-local genetic effects on human facial shape". User2554330's code looks more like what is presented in the paper. But your plot may be right since I used  facial data from only 4 participants to perform the clustering analysis. I am interested in why your plot is different from user2554330's.

Comment: @Patrick Hmmm weird. The only difference is the option `meshColor = "vertices"`, but I thought that the default behavior is to color by vertices, so I don't understand why the outputs differ.