# Is there an r function to produce excel 3d plot?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

Is there any way to produce excel 3d plot in r?

I have a matrix and I would like to plot it in 3d surface format using R.
I managed to do it in excel and it gives me this plot https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hNqCguPX_ar8ueSK-u-yHTUYZxdyT_cE

I would like to produce same plot but with R
this plot is produced with this data

```
m<-matrix(c(7,73,195,195,416,625,120,52,178,178,349,454,6,83,164,164,244,0,3,52,150,150,329,330),nrow = 4, ncol = 6, byrow = T)
```

Comment: maybe  this is something you could do with the ``ggplot2`` and ``gg3D`` packages.

Comment: How to interpret this matrix? Are the columns / rows variable? Does each cell represent intensity?

Comment: @Gainz Could you please provide me a code for this? I tried all possibilities but I failed at the end

Comment: @bbiasi Yes rows and columns are variables let say lat and long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the dataset in use is not available, so there is no way to faithfully reproduce the image and expand the details.

To create the contour surface, it is interesting to use the `ggplot2` package with the `geom_raster` function. But this will return a continuous surface.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

x <- seq(1, 6, 1)
y <- seq(0, 3, 1)
grid <- expand.grid(x = x,
                    y = y)
m <- matrix(c(7,73,195,195,416,625,120,52,178,178,349,454,6,
            83,164,164,244,0,3,52,150,150,329,330), 
            nrow = 4, ncol = 6, byrow = T)
m2 <- m %>% 
  t %>% as.data.frame()
grid <- grid %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(response = c(m2$V1, m2$V2, m2$V3, m2$V4))

Palet <- c("royalblue2", "orangered3", "lavenderblush3", "gold3")

ggplot2::ggplot(grid, aes(x, y, z = response)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = response)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = Palet, limits = c(0, 800)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

In addition, it is possible to perform data manipulation and work with the discrete `fill`. Where for each interval, a color will be assigned.

```
grid2 <- grid %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(cor = ifelse(response >= 0 & response < 200, 1,
                             ifelse(response >= 200 & response < 400, 2,
                                    ifelse(response >= 400 & response < 600, 3,
                                           ifelse(response >= 600, 4, "error")))))

ggplot2::ggplot(grid2, aes(x, y, z = response)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = cor)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = Palet, labels = c("0-200", "200-400",
                                               "400-600", "600-800"),
                    name = "") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

---

However, if it is considered that in matrix `m` each cell is intensity, it is possible to generate a 3D plot.

```
library(plot3D)
persp3D(z = m, theta = 60)
```

[image]

[3D surface plot from 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225752/3d-surface-plot-from-2d-matrix)

[Plot 3D data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720526/plot-3d-data-in-r)

[Impressive package for 3D and 4D graph - R software and data visualization](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization)

Comment: Thanks for help, however it is still very far from plot made by Microsoft excel (attached)

Comment: @Alaa see this: [link1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), [link2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow). Thanks.